# How do I do this?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, frontend

Due to my situation with a past job, I have fallen behind on my Front End skills and would like to beef them up in my spare time. I am going to tackle a project like the slider/article reveal located at:

-/keyword-history+of+air+Jordan">http://www.footlocker.com/*-*/keyword-history+of+air+Jordan

I understand how they accomplish the changing of the images up top (roman numerals) when selected (just use a selected class). I also understand how they show and hide the articles. What I want to understand is how they accomplished the slider bar that makes the roman numerals slide left to right.

I am going to be attempting this on my own and would like an understanding of how to accomplish that slider as I have no idea where to start.

Also, do you know of any good tutorials for creating sliders like the one at the top of http://www.footlocker.com/ where it has images under it that when clicked advance the slider. Thanks!

Mike

Comment: There is hundred of this kind of slider, search e.g nivo slider which use more effect than the one at footlocker. Create your own slider is not that hard too

Comment: nivo slider doesn't do the things I listed. What about the roman numerals that you can slide to the side but they change the picture when you click them? What I'm looking for is a good tutorial on rolling my own slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to study up on the STYLING of the div that is used to make the slider work. Once I nailed that the rest was easy.